# What can we do to improve the site visibility for "Electronics Q&A" searches?

Tags: discussion

On a whim I Googled the following phrases:

- "Electronics Q&A"

  *The `electronics.stackexchange.com` site was about the 125th result on the first query.*
- "Electrical Engineering Q&A"

  *In the top ten.*
- "Programming Q&A"

  *Stack Overflow came up #1 for the last query.*

What concerns me is that if I didn't know about the site, I wouldn't find it using the term I use most to describe my hobby: **Electronics**

I usually think of the word "electrical" as being associated with higher power projects (mains wiring of residential/commercial buildings, for example). I realize one goal of the site is to dissuade commercial electronics questions ("Which guitar amp should I buy?"), maybe that was a partial reason behind the rename of the site.

What can we do to improve site visibility using the term "electronics?" I'm not suggesting a rename, but raising a concern that the site doesn't seem sufficiently ranked when using this keyword.

**Update:**

As of 2014-03-22, doing a Google search (in private mode without being logged in) for "Electronics Q&A" now brings up *this very question* as the 17th result. (Paradoxical, maybe?)

I gave up trying to find the main page (electronics.stackexchange.com) in the results after the 200th result.

Comment: Positive and negative there, most of the googling public looking for electronics Q&A is going to be looking for consumer electronics support.

Comment: Do you really want hords of unwashed masses to whom "electronics" means a TV, phone, and remote coming here asking lots of questions we have to close?  If someone can't think of the term "electrical engineering", then we're probably better off without them.

Comment: @Olin I agree, upon reflection. It might be useful to see what "Electronics Engineering" results in...

Comment: Maybe this question is better phrased as "What can we do to improve the site visibility for “Electronics **Engineering** Q&A” searches?"

Comment: When I google for specific topics, the links to EE.SE threads come up in the top 5-10 often.  Years ago, I've found StackOverflow like that.